# Detecting vulnerabilities in webpages using java

Tags: java, web-crawler, xss, sql-injection, malware-detection

I am developing a web application in java which uses web crawler to get content from web pages and perform content filtration and also detection of vulnerabilities in those web pages.
But i am not able to get any content related to  detection of vulnerabilities in web pages using java. Any idea or help regarding this is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well this isn't really java-related. Once you know what to do to detect vulnerabilities you can implement it in every language you want, but you need to know the theory behind it first.

Comment: check [websecurity](http://www.websecurify.com/vulnerabilities.html)

Comment: Thanks for the response...yes will study different types of attacks and will try to come up with strategies to detect vulnerabilities.